# Elasticsearch - Rank userIds based on score

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I'm trying to migrate some of the queries of our old MySQL database to our new Elasticsearch setup. The data is a little bit more complex but boils down to the following:

I've got an index containing a lot of scores. Each score represents the points a player scored in a particular game.

```
{
  "userId": 2,
  "scoreId": 3457,
  "game": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "scrabble"
  },
  "date": 1340047100,
  "score": 56,
  // and more game data
}
```

`scoreId` is the unique id for this score, `game.id` is the id of that type of game.

```
{
  "userId": 6,
  "gameId": 3479,
  "game": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "risk"
  },
  "date": "1380067200",
  "score": 100,
  // and more game data
}
```

Over the years a lot of different games are played and I would like to rank the best players for each type of game. The ranking is based on the best 6 games of each player. So for example, if a player played scrabble 10 times, only its 6 best scores count for its total score.

I would like to create a list like:

```
// Scrabble ranking:
# | user | total points  
1 |  2   | 4500
2 |  6   | 3200
2 |  23  | 1500
```

The reason for the migration is that the old MySQL queries first get a list of all the distinct users for each game, and then executes another query for EACH user to get its best 6 scores. I hoped that I could use the aggregates of elastic to do it all in just one query but so far I can't make it work.

The problem is that after a couple of hours of reading the elastic docs it seems that my problem is more complex than the examples. Maybe if someone can point me a bit in the right direction I can continue my search. At least this is not getting me anywhere:

```
GET /my-index/scores/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": { "game.id": 6 }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "scores": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
      }
    },
    "top_scores_user": {
      "top_hits": {
        "sort": [{
          "score": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }],
        "size" : 6
      }
    }
  },
   "size": 0
}
```

I'm using elastic 2.3 but there's a chance I could upgrade if it's really necessary.

Comment: Can you detail why the query you tried already doesn't answer your requirement? Haven't looked at it in detail (testing something out), but a first read of it seems to be the right thing...

Comment: The problem I see with the current query is that you're not able to sort the users by the sum of their 6 best scores, i.e. for each user you get the 6 best scores, but you cannot rank them according to their sum. Is that right?

Comment: Actually you have a small error in there (not formatting error), but functional. The second aggregation should be a sub-agg of the first one.

Comment: I don't think he's summing up all those scores @Val. The initial MySQL query doesn't say anything about a sum. I think it's just ranking by the highest score for a particular game.

Comment: Fair enough @AndreiStefan I was referring to the last table that mentions `total points` so I thought those were the sum of the 6 best scores (per game per user).

Comment: And if it's only that sub-agg mistake it should:`{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "game.id": 6
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "scores": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_scores_user": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 6
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}`

Comment: Hm, could be @Val...

Comment: Sorry, I missed the incoming comments here. Andrei, The query I tried does not answer my requirement because it returns the best 6 scores in general, not grouped by user. But Val you are indeed right, there was an error in the query, the second aggregation should be a sub of the first one.. I indeed also need a sum of the 6 best scores (per game per user). Maybe this could be done with scripting when the 6 best games per user are calculated?

Comment: -> returns the best 6 scores in general <- no sorry. it does return a grouped result per user (with that mistake fixed.. ) but it does not calculate the sum, and since the most popular game contains around 2000 unique users, I can't calculate the sum and the ranking client side.. that would take a long time.

Comment: In all fairness, the error in the query was spotted by @AndreiStefan not me :-)

Comment: @Val would have spotted that as well, I'm sure :-).

Comment: Haha whoops :p credits to you @AndreiStefan!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `top_hits` will not let you achieve what you need, because you cannot act upon the fields that are returned for each documents in the top hits aggregation.

One way to get around this is to use a top-level `terms` aggregation for users (as you did) and then for each user another `terms` sub-aggregation for the scores that you can sort in decreasing order and taking only the 6 best ones. Finally, using a [pipeline `sum_bucket` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html), you can sum up those 6 scores for each user.

```
POST /my-index/scores/_search    
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "game.id": 6
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {              <--- segment by user
        "field": "userId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "best_scores": {
          "terms": {          <--- 6 best scores for user
            "field": "score",
            "order": {
              "_term": "desc"
            },
            "size": 6
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_score": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "score"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "total_points": {     <--- total points for the user based on 6 best scores
          "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "best_scores > total_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that one drawback of this solution is if the user had twice the exact same score, you'll get the 7 best scores and not the 6 best ones and the `total_score` value will be too high. We could use the `avg` instead of `sum` metric aggregation, but if we do this, we'll ignore one of the score occurrence, which is not good either.

Also note that it would be ideal to sort the users according to their `total_points` value, but it is not possible to sort using pipeline aggregations (since they run after the reduce phase). The sorting will need to happen on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It looks promising but I'm not sure if I can work around the 2 drawbacks :(. The first one is a problem because there a lot of games with only a limited set of outcomes and a lot of players played the same games multiple times. The second because some games are played by over 3000 players. Sorting those on the client side will take a long time... But maybe there could be another way, I'm diving a bit deeper the aggregations you've come up with. Thanks! Let me know if you have another suggestion.

Comment: Would it be possible to act upon the fields that are returned for each document in the top hits aggregation with a custom script? For example with a scripted_metric aggregation?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, what client side language are you using?

Comment: Regarding your second comment, the answer is no. It wouldn't be fun as the solution would be too simple :-)

Comment: I'm using php... I managed to get something working yesterday by indeed letting php do al the sorting. It's faster then I thought it would be.. but it will not scale that well. But using some inline groovy script would not be cheating right? That would be a great solution! There's still a 500p bounty :D

Comment: Great you made it work! Using scripting is not cheating, but I'm not sure how it would help here. Still thinking...

Comment: Well, scripting does basically what you would do in your own programming language. Now it depends on the speed of the scripts and of that of your programming language of choice. But, using scripts you will not use the true/native power of Elasticsearch and Lucene. That's why we recommend, as much as possible, to either adjust the data/mapping/queries to fit your needs in a way to use the native queries/data structures of ES, rather than making all possible from query point of view. But I agree there are situations where one cannot change the data for example, and the only option is a script.

Comment: Fair enough, @AndreiStefan, but in this specific context I'm not sure how scripting would help overcome the two shortcomings I've mentioned, i.e. sort the user terms and make sure that `total_score` comprises only 6 scores and not more not less. Unless we can of course completely revise the data model.

Comment: Check. That makes sense. Well, I'm the ES noob, but maybe with scripting there would be a way to do act upon the results that come back from the `top_hits` aggregation. Or use a scripting aggregation instead of `top_hits` to get back a result that other aggregations could act upon? Regarding changing the model, I think there would still be room to change it, as long as it is done in a way that does not creates a lot of troubles when updating the records if needed..

Comment: So if we sum it up, your PHP code now handles the sorting and that "sort of" works. You claim that it will not scale well, which might or might not be true (i.e. you also thought that client-side sorting would not scale well, but discovered that it wasn't that scary after all). You now have 3000 users playing the same game. By how many orders of magnitude do you expect this number to grow (10000, 100000, 1000000, ...)? If you expect the same order of magnitude, then your PHP code will be fine, I would start worrying if you envision having an n-fold growth.

Comment: The data in `top_hits` cannot be acted upon and scripts can only act on a single document at a time, while you'd need it to be able to act on a series of aggregated buckets instead. Pipeline aggregations already help a lot here (to calculate the total score), but given the way they are computed, we cannot leverage them any further... As I see it, the only way is to rethink the data model a little bit.

Comment: This would help a lot: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14928 @AndreiStefan do you have any internal insights about this issue?

Comment: So to give you a bit more context, I simplified my post a bit to make it easier to read for potential helpers like you guys. In reality, I'm not dealing with games but with climbing crags and 60k users who climb all over the globe. For each route they climb in a crag they get points and the ranking shows the best climbers for a certain crag :). I thought indeed that sorting 3k of results with PHP would be slow but it seems to be okay. And you might indeed be right about the scaling. First I should not worry about it at this point. (1/2)

Comment: I can always cache the result of the sorting with Memcached. I might even be able to apply the same kind of query and sorting for the overall ranking (regardless of the crag, or game in this metaphor). I'll reward you the bounty. Thanks again for helping me solve this. (2/2)